# MS Access Time Format changing from hh:nn to h:nn

Tags: ms-access, formatting, form-control

I'm having this frustrating problem in Access. I have a form with a text box control, formatted as hh:nn. However, if the time has a single digit hour, such as the time 08:45, when I leave the text box Access seems to change the format to h:nn, displaying only 8:45.

This causes difficulties the next time a user enters the text box and tries to change the time or even just leave the time as is.

Why is Access displaying the hh:nn format as h:nn? How can I fix this?

Comment: That I cannot reproduce. That said, I can't see what trouble it could to editing the field value, so probably something else is going on.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue because of "the regional Long Time format" as explained in the below reference.

[Reference](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/edb9e80b-7c00-4b67-bd3c-b3ef6fadda2a/textbox-format-quothhquot-not-displaying-leading-zero?forum=accessdev&prof=required)

> My regional Long Time format was set to "h:mm:ss tt".  I changed it to "hh:mm:ss tt", exited Access, restarted and reopened the test database I was using, and now the dates, in table and form, are displaying the hour with the leading zero.